# Question about Normal distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am trying the derivation of Normal distribution and I am confused in the following step, let me define the experiment first
Suppose we are throwing a dart on $2$D- coordinate plane and 0 is a bullseye. and suppose $\phi$ be a function in which if I put any point it will give me the probability of that point that dart is hitting that point or not now assume a point $f(x,y)$ and the small area $dA$ around this point then it says that probability in area $dA$ is nothing but  $f(x,y)dA$ where $f(x,y)$ is PDF, My question is why is probability is given like this?

Comment: A little more information about the context of $f(x,y) \ dA$ is helpful.

Comment: This is just how integration works - if done properly, adding an infinite number of infinitely small bits gives a meaningful result.

Comment: @callculus42 https://medium.com/@curiousincosmos/normal-distribution-probability-density-function-derivation-872c4f9d514d